# jQuery Photo Gallery Only Loads on Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope, fancybox-2, photo-gallery

I have a problem where my photo gallery only loads on page refresh. I believe the fix is quite simple, except I am having no luck.. I think I need to call a function after a .append() function has loaded.

The photo gallery is quite complex. It has 4 components:

1. Append images sourced from three different xml files with divs.
2. Image divs are given css, and overlays from mosaic jquery plugin.
3. Images are arranged in groups by isotope jquery plugin to show and hide certain photos.
4. Images use fancybox jquery plugin when clicked.

First I am appending images loaded onto a page from three different xml feeds. This code works fine and the images are appended even if they don't show up on the page (using inspect their divs and sizes are there).

### Append Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:'/gallery/apartment/PhotoGallery.xml',  // Add your url to your photo gallery xml feed
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: xmlParser1
    });

    // don't touch anything under me
    function xmlParser1(xml) {
        $(xml).find("img").each(function () {                       
        $(".apartment-images").append('<div class="mosaic-block third fade"><a href="/gallery/apartment/' + $(this).attr('src') + '" class="mosaic-overlay fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="' + $(this).attr('alt') + '"></a><div class="mosaic-backdrop"><img src="/gallery/apartment/' + $(this).attr('src') + '?Action=thumbnail&Width=500&Height=375&algorithm=fill_proportional" alt="' + $(this).attr('alt') + '" /></div></div></div>');
        });
    // don't touch anything above me
    }

$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:'/gallery/views/PhotoGallery.xml',  // Add your url to your photo gallery xml feed
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: xmlParser2
    });

    // don't touch anything under me
    function xmlParser2(xml) {
        $(xml).find("img").each(function () {                       
        $(".the-views-images").append('<div class="mosaic-block third fade"><a href="/gallery/views/' + $(this).attr('src') + '" class="mosaic-overlay fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="' + $(this).attr('alt') + '"></a><div class="mosaic-backdrop"><img src="/gallery/views/' + $(this).attr('src') + '?Action=thumbnail&Width=500&Height=375&algorithm=fill_proportional" alt="' + $(this).attr('alt') + '" /></div></div></div>');
        });
    // don't touch anything above me
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:'/gallery/moana/PhotoGallery.xml',  // Add your url to your photo gallery xml feed
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: xmlParser3
    });

    // don't touch anything under me
    function xmlParser3(xml) {
        $(xml).find("img").each(function () {                       
        $(".moana-images").append('<div class="mosaic-block third fade"><a href="/gallery/moana/' + $(this).attr('src') + '" class="mosaic-overlay fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="' + $(this).attr('alt') + '"></a><div class="mosaic-backdrop"><img src="/gallery/moana/' + $(this).attr('src') + '?Action=thumbnail&Width=500&Height=375&algorithm=fill_proportional" alt="' + $(this).attr('alt') + '" /></div></div></div>');
        });
    // don't touch anything above me
    }
});
```

Then there are three pieces of code inside a main.js file (I think these reference the functions in their js files) that give the images jQuery features:

- **MAIN JS:** http://moanabeach.businesscatalyst.com/js/main.js

### Mosaic Function

```
mosaic : function(){
                    $('.fade').mosaic();
                }, // mosaic
```

### Isotope Function

```
isotype: function() {

                    $(window).load(function(){
                            if($('#thumb-gallery').size() === 0){return;}

            var $container = $('#thumb-gallery');
            $container.isotope({
                masonry: {
                    columnWidth: 1 //was 26
                },
                sortBy: 'number',
                getSortData: {
                    number: function($elem) {
                        var number = $elem.hasClass('element') ? $elem.find('.number').text() : $elem.attr('data-number');
                        return parseInt(number, 10);
                    },
                    alphabetical: function($elem) {
                        var name = $elem.find('.name'),
                            itemText = name.length ? name : $elem;
                        return itemText.text();
                    }
                }
            });
            var $optionSets = $('.meta.option-set'),
                $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

                    $optionLinks.click(function() {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        // don't proceed if already selected
                        if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
                        $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
                        $this.addClass('selected');
                        // make option object dynamically, i.e. { filter: '.my-filter-class' }
                        var options = {},
                            key = $optionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
                            value = $this.attr('data-option-value');
                        // parse 'false' as false boolean
                        value = value === 'false' ? false : value;
                        options[key] = value;
                        if (key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function') {
                            // changes in layout modes need extra logic
                            changeLayoutMode($this, options)
                        } else {
                            // otherwise, apply new options
                            $container.isotope(options);
                        }
                        return false;
                    });

                    }); // window.load()


        } // isotope()
```

### Fancybox Function

```
fancyBox : function(){
$('.fancybox').fancybox();
                }
```

### Each of these reference functions from:

- http://moanabeach.businesscatalyst.com/js/mosaic.1.0.1.min.js
- http://moanabeach.businesscatalyst.com/js/jquery.isotope.js
- http://moanabeach.businesscatalyst.com/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.4

**The Live Gallery can be viewed here which only loads correctly on first load and page refresh:**

- http://moanabeach.businesscatalyst.com/gallery

**It does not load after clicking other links on the website OR using the back button in your browser.**

What seems to be happening is the #thumb-gallery height is loaded before the images so the height is too small and doesn't display the images. If you click on the left hand menu the height is refreshed and the gallery works fine. The two values that change are the #thumb-image height:

```
**PAGE LOAD:**  
<div class="four-fifths right last thumb-gallery super-list variable-sizes isotope" id="thumb-gallery" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 98px;">


**PAGE REFRESH:**  
<div class="four-fifths right last thumb-gallery super-list variable-sizes isotope" id="thumb-gallery" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 1359px;">
```

Note: Height is dependant on browser window.

Also, the .isotope-item -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); on each of the images groups doesn't load correctly unless on page refresh. On normal page load all the image groups are placed on top of each other, where as on page refresh they have a -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px 123px 0px), spacing them out vertically.

I assume this all comes down to one of the mosaic, isotope or fancybox functions (If not all of the functions.) to be called at the end of the append function. That way the images will load and be appended before anything else happens. However, I am not sure how to do this.

I will promptly respond if you need more information.

Live Page: moanabeach.businesscatalyst.com/gallery

Thank you in advance.

*Please note: I didn't create any of the jquery files (main, isotope, mosaic and fancybox) so I do not have a knowledge on the connection between the main.js and other files. They came with the template. The only code I have modified is the append code.*

### Attempts:

- Playing around with document.ready and window.load and the various functions.
- Position of javascript code and files

Comment: did you fix it? works fine for me unless I am missing something (browser/OS)?

Comment: I am on Macintosh 10.8.5 / Google Chrome and same problem in Safari. Same problem on Windows Phone 8 / IE. Are you on the gallery page? or home page? I fixed the home page one. What OS and Browser are you using so I can check. It works properly on first page load but if you click an internal page link and then go back or click gallery on the menu again it doesn't load... Maybe yours cached correctly.

Comment: Also, I just checked windows 7 / IE and same problem even on first page load.